How to use parse_query() to add an additional filter based on content to page search?
I want to add another filter box to my admin "pages" screen, let's call it search2.
I want to be able to filter the results that I searched to be limited to only pages that contains search2 in the post_content. I've added the box and I can get the input to my function, but I can't figure out what to change in the query. I want this to work in the admin page whether or not 's' is empty & I don't want it to change what's in the 's' field because I want these to be able to be two different strings.
I'm adding the filter to parse_query() and my function looks like:
public function modifyFilterQuery($query){
    global $pagenow;
    $search2_filter = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'search2_filter', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    if (true === in_array($post_type, ['page', '', ''], true) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow) {
        if (false === empty($search2_filter)) {
            //What Should I do here? Something like:
            //$query->set(?);
            //?
        }
    }

    return $query;
}


There is only one parameter that will filter your results to posts that contain a value in the content, s aka search, but doing so would break the search box. Unless you write code that on save updates a flag to indicate if the post contains that in its post content you can't have both

Is there a way I can add "AND post_content like %$search2_filter%" to the query?

not using WP_Query, you'd need to modify the raw SQL which carries its own consequences and compatibility problems. If you need to filter by something though it's much much easier and significantly faster to use a taxonomy, that's the whole point of terms and taxonomies, filtering/grouping posts
